# How to merge KeyReleaseEvent with Button

Tags: c++, qt, qpushbutton, qkeyevent

How to merge `KeyReleaseEvent` and `QPushButton` using `signal`.
I mean whenever user will press enter key button should call some function using SLOT. So what i have to use in the signal?

```
void mywindow::keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    switch(event->key())
    {
        case Qt::Key_Enter:
            connect(button1, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(fileNew()));
            connect(button2, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(file()));
        break;  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to click some button when pressing the enter key. You can just call the  [`QAbstractButton::click()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qabstractbutton.html#click) function to perform a click.

```
connect(button1,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(fileNew()));
connect(button2,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(file())); //do this in your constructor, or somewhere else.. just make sure you only do this once
```

```
void mywindow::keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    switch(event->key())
    {
        case Qt::Key_Enter:
            button1->click();    
        break;    
    }
}
```

Comment: -1: What about the `button2` and what about dynamic connections?

Comment: You can use hasFocus() and check whether the button focus is in button1 or 2 and then call that button by click()

Comment: @RedX What about dynamic connections? OP didn't ask anything related to that. And `button2` works the same way. I demonstrated how to click a button programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

There is [shortcut](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qabstractbutton.html#shortcut-prop) property to handle such case.
I recommend to use [QAction](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qaction.html#details) with [shortcut](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qaction.html#shortcut-prop) value. There is lost of bonus functionality.